# Telerik RadDaigram does not contain definition for SwitchGridVisibility

Tags: wpf, silverlight, telerik, raddiagram

I am trying to switch off the grid visibility of a RadDiagram I have.

I am creating a User Control using Telerik controls within a Silverlight Project (sharing the control with a WPF Library).

It seems that RadDiagram Property is not found. ([RadDiagram Commands](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/raddiagrams-features-commands.html) - Found property here)

**PS**: I am creating and filling the shape programmatically. Therefore, I need to an approach to switch the grid off that apply to Style attribute in Resource Dictionary or a simple programmatic property set / function call.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to turn off the BackGroundGrid or BackGroundPageGrid is to use these attached properties:

```
 <telerik:RadDiagram x:Name="diagram" Margin="30"                           
                     primitives:BackgroundGrid.IsGridVisible="False"
                     primitives:BackgroundPageGrid.IsGridVisible="False"
```

where primitives is defined like so:

```
xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.Diagrams.Primitives; assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Diagrams"
```

If you need to bind the command for switching the BackGroundGrid On / Off , you can use this syntax:

```
 <telerik:RadButton Command="telerik:DiagramCommands.SwitchGridVisibility"
                         CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=diagram}"/>
```

Comment: how can I switch the grid programmatically though. Since I create the diagram in code.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically in code-behind here is how it is done:

```
Telerik.Windows.Controls.Diagrams.Primitives.BackgroundGrid.SetIsGridVisible(this.myDiagram, false);
```

Source: [Switch Grid Visibility](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/diagram/switchgridvisibility-is-not-defined-for-raddiagram.aspx#2738705)